# Where to put Scrollviewer visual studio phone

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I was trying to put scollviewer into this page before Grid, then all textboxes disappearded. Where should I put scrollviewer? It says Warning   1   The 'Grid' start tag on line 17 position 6 does not match the end tag of 'phone:PhoneApplicationPage'. Line 74, position 3. C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Excercises_Copy1\Excercises\Running jogging.xaml   74  3   Excercises

and, closing tag for element Grid was not found

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Excercises.Running_jogging"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="17*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="437*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="26*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="36*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="83*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="649*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="117*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="229*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="Let's get started" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="152" Grid.Column="1" />

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,24,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock2" Text="Running is simple and healthy sport and it's also one of the most effective aerobic exercises. Additionally, running does not require large financial outlays. By running you will strengthen the circulatory and immune system and reduce tension caused by stress. Running also helps losing fat." TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="444" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TextBlock3" Text="Warm-up before running" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,36,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock4" Text="TRUNK BENDING; Feet at shoulder height, straight legs at knees during the exercise. Bend to the left leg, then to the right and  at the end straighten the body. Repeat 20 times. " TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="456" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="167" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,156,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock5" Text="PLANTAR FASCIA STRETCH; Sit on a chair or stool and cross your right foot over your left thigh. Grasp the toes of your right foot and pull them upward toward your shin. Hold this stretched position for at least 10 seconds. Release and repeat two to three times. Reverse. " VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="444" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="222" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,329,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock6" Text="SEATED HEEL CORD STRETCH; Sit on floor or bench with both feet extended straight out in front of you. Do not lock knees. Wrap a towel around one foot and pull foot toward you. Push foot against the towel for five seconds while you hold the towel still. Relax foot and pull back toward you again. Repeat steps 3 and 4 twice. Reverse." VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="444" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TextBlock7" Text="Running test" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="43,557,0,0" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="149" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,593,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock8" Text="Test is to run continuously with constat pace. The best pace is a jogtrot a little faster than a fast walking. Run as long as you can and measure the time. According to your time choose the right week of the training." VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="450" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,790,0,-1018" x:Name="TextBlock9" Width="456"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"><Run Text="- Less then 2 minutes - begin with fast walking" /><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 2-4 minutes - Week 1"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 5-6 minutes - Week 3"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 7-8 minutes - Week 4"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 9-10 minutes - Week 6"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 11-12 minutes - Week 7"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 13-14 minutes - Week 8"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- More then 15 miuntes - Week 10 "/></TextBlock>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Excercises;component/Images/tlo.png" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>

        <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: You can put it outside, but then you need to set "Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"" on the ScrollViewer and not the ContentPanel grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is really complex, but you can place the scrollviewer inside your ContentPanel and make a new grid inside of it

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0">
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="36*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="83*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="649*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="117*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="229*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="Let's get started" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="152" Grid.Column="1" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,24,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock2" Text="Running is simple and healthy sport and it's also one of the most effective aerobic exercises. Additionally, running does not require large financial outlays. By running you will strengthen the circulatory and immune system and reduce tension caused by stress. Running also helps losing fat." TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="444" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TextBlock3" Text="Warm-up before running" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,36,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock4" Text="TRUNK BENDING; Feet at shoulder height, straight legs at knees during the exercise. Bend to the left leg, then to the right and  at the end straighten the body. Repeat 20 times. " TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="456" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="167" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,156,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock5" Text="PLANTAR FASCIA STRETCH; Sit on a chair or stool and cross your right foot over your left thigh. Grasp the toes of your right foot and pull them upward toward your shin. Hold this stretched position for at least 10 seconds. Release and repeat two to three times. Reverse. " VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="444" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="222" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,329,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock6" Text="SEATED HEEL CORD STRETCH; Sit on floor or bench with both feet extended straight out in front of you. Do not lock knees. Wrap a towel around one foot and pull foot toward you. Push foot against the towel for five seconds while you hold the towel still. Relax foot and pull back toward you again. Repeat steps 3 and 4 twice. Reverse." VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="444" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TextBlock7" Text="Running test" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="43,557,0,0" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Height="149" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,593,0,0" x:Name="TextBlock8" Text="Test is to run continuously with constat pace. The best pace is a jogtrot a little faster than a fast walking. Run as long as you can and measure the time. According to your time choose the right week of the training." VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="450" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,790,0,-1018" x:Name="TextBlock9" Width="456"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"><Run Text="- Less then 2 minutes - begin with fast walking" /><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 2-4 minutes - Week 1"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 5-6 minutes - Week 3"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 7-8 minutes - Week 4"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 9-10 minutes - Week 6"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 11-12 minutes - Week 7"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- 13-14 minutes - Week 8"/><Run Text=" "/><LineBreak/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="- More then 15 miuntes - Week 10 "/></TextBlock>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Excercises;component/Images/tlo.png" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You forgot about closing first grid. It shows me error about it. So?

Comment: Still the same. it shows me an error in last line : "</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>" and "closing tag for element "grid" was not found", any ideas?

Comment: The xaml as I have posted has all closing tags. It might be another control that you have that is not closed.

Comment: your LayoutRoot Grid is not closed. Close it before the application bar code. You can also remove the columns from the layoutroot based on that xaml